# Unwrapping an AST

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm designing a save file format, and for simplicity's sake, it's a subset of YAML, with 3 primitive types, and 2 data structures.

My AST, written in Scala:

```
sealed trait SaveElement

/**
 * Trait for save data primitives
 */
sealed trait SaveKey extends SaveElement
case class Integer(i: Long) extends SaveKey
case class FloatingPoint(f: Double) extends SaveKey
case class Str(s: String) extends SaveKey

case class SaveList(elems: SaveElement*) extends SaveElement
case class SaveHash(keyValuePairs: Map[SaveKey, SaveElement]) extends SaveElement
```

It's quite basic, and does not much more beyond wrapping basic Scala types. Given the AST that I have, how should I convert between the concrete types used in my program, and the types in the AST, in a hopefully simple manner?

Of course, I could be entirely going about this the wrong way, in which case I would also appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

**Edit** After thinking harder about what I'm asking, I've come to the conclusion that what I want to do is unwrap the AST into Scala types. I want to do this in a manner that doesn't involve typecasting the `SaveElement`s into the case classes that they have to be (because of prior knowledge of how the AST was built in the first place).

Comment: I guess that depends on what your application needs.  What I have done is to return a top-level 'model' from the parse and walk the model extracting what I need from it.  You can add support for this into your case classes or use pattern matching from the app to do what is necessary.  Without knowing more about what you really need I don't know how to be more specific.  Does this help?

Comment: I guess for me it's more about unwrapping the AST. My current solution involves disgusting amounts of type casting, because I cannot figure out how to have a single function unwrap and then return the correct type.

Comment: Is your application in Scala as well?

Comment: Yup, it is. So I'm hoping for a nice Scala solution to this.

Comment: OK. After reading your edit I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  After all, parsing will return *something* based on the case classes you defined and you will have to unwrap that *somewhere* and that unwrap code will have to understand the AST structure, right?

Comment: I guess it's like this: give a function that takes in a `SaveElement`, and returns the unwrapped Scala type, of itself, and any sub-elements. So if this function is given a `SaveList` it should return a Scala list, with all the individual members unwrapped as well, so a `SaveList[Integer]` will return a `List[Long]`. Looking back on what I'm trying to achieve, I'm coming to the conclusion it's not possible, because I'm unifying over the types, and dividing them would require using `Any`, which then needs me to typecast anyway, defeating the purpose.

Comment: Then my answer below is *almost* what you want, I think.  Just replace `mdl: Model` with `elem: SaveElement`, and you can eliminate the `for` construct as well.  The function can further be recursive to handle sub-elements.

Comment: Hmm, I do get what you're saying, and it does sound mostly correct. But I'd like to know how to deal with mixed types. For example, because the list's elements are of type `SaveElement`, each individual element's most specialised type can be fairly different, with the least upper bound on the types probably resulting in something like `Any`. I want to avoid that and the resultant typecasting; I'll assume that's impossible, but I'll give it a couple of days to see if no one can have an interesting solution to it. If not, I'll accept your answer then.

Comment: IIUC that is where the use of pattern matching comes into play.  You would need to extend the match block with a `case` for each of the different case classes you could receive.  If your model is more complex than what you described above I suppose it could get a little messy, though, to do it all in a single function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is as follows.

```
model = <result of parsing input>
extractElements(model)
```

where:

```
def extractElements(mdl: Model): // or whatever your parser returns
    // Assuming the model contains a top-level collection of SaveElements
    // in a SaveList called 'elements'
    for (element <- mdl.elements.elems) {
        element match {
            case SaveMap(pairs) => // do something with the map
            case SaveList(elems) => // do something with the list
            ...
        }
    }
```

You can modify this approach to suit your needs.  Is this what you were after?

Comment: Not quite, I've given more thought to what I'm trying to achieve, and I've updated the question to reflect that.